# Make Pythonanywhere web server act like Django's built in server

Tags: ubuntu, python, ubuntu-14.04, django

Django's built in server updates apps in real time. In PythonAnywhere one has to reload manually. Is there a way to make PythonAnywhere web server act like the built in feature of Django?

Answer (score 1):

The difference in behavior comes from the fact that Django's built-in server is designed as a development server while serving your app through uWSGI (or whatever it is you use) is more of a production state.

AFAIK, you can't have the server reload the whole app on every request but you can have uWSGI reload the app when you `touch` the `wsgi.py`.

Comment: what do you mean touch the wsgi.py?

Comment: `touch` is a UNIX command that sets the modification timestamp of a file to now. uWSGI can be set to reload apps whose entry point has an updated timestamp.